# Как сделать предпросмотр ссылки на сайт в Telegram?

Tags: html, html5, telegram

Как можно сделать так, что бы при отправлении ссылки на мой сайт в Telegram отображался предпросмотр открываемой страницы? Не Instant View, а что бы просто выводился description и title.

Comment: Если я ничего не путаю то за это отвечает Open Graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте open Graph разметку в head своей страницы.

Пример с IMDB страница фильма "скала".

```
<html prefix="og: //ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<title>The Rock (1996)</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="//www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="//ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
...
</head>
...
</html>
```

Своё описание можно добавить через тег `og:description`

```
<meta property="og:description" content="Описание моей страницы" />
```

Подробнее о нюансах работы в мессенджерах: https://mediaskunk.ru/2016/02/opengraph-messengers/

Ряд нюансов для telegram: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34707915/how-do-you-clear-the-open-graph-cache-of-an-url-on-telegram

Генератор тегов нужного вам вида: 
https://a.pr-cy.ru/tools/open-graph-generator/

Проверка open Graph тегов на странице:
https://sitechecker.pro/ru/open-graph/

Подробная документация на русском:
https://ruogp.me/

Comment: Спасибо! Подскажите,а сейчас возможно добавить полноразмерную картинку в превью? Как в этом примере?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34707915/how-do-you-clear-the-open-graph-cache-of-an-url-on-telegram
Я пробовал использовать twitter и og message, но картинка все равно очень маленькая и расположена сбоку от основной информации

Comment: @Zoom кажется это то, что вам нужно:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53685817/obtain-a-good-big-large-image-in-rich-link-preview-in-telegram

`<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="{IMAGE URL}" />`